# access mdb - Microsoft JET Database Engine erro '80004005'

Tags: banco-de-dados, iis, asp

De uma hora para outra (após uma atualização do windows) meus arquivos MDB não abrem mais via IIS - ASP) com a mensagem:

> Microsoft JET Database Engine erro '80004005' - erro não específico.
>
> A conexão parou de funcionar para qualquer arquivo MDB.
>
> Set oConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 'oconn.open
>   "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & "Data Source=" &
>   Server.Mappath("/prgrm/seguros.mdb") & ";"

Reinstalei a engine.
Reconfigurei o IIS para rodar aplicativos em 32 bits.
Verifiquei permissões de pastas e do arquivo MDB.

Comment: você tentou remover o update do windows?

Comment: sim (acho). Voltei ao ponto de restauração anterior.